# Datetime - GetValueOrDefault

Tags: c#, datetime, default-value

Can I check if this is the default value without using a hard coding values  `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`? If it is the default set it to null?

```cs
DateTime? dt= null;
DateTime? datetimeVM;

datetimeVM = dt.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: datetimeVM==DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# has built-in keyword for getting default value of a type: `default(T)` where `T` is your wanted type.

So if you want to check if your `Nullable<DateTime>` (thats why there's `?` by `DateTime`) has default `DateTime` value, just use

```
if (datetimeVM == default(DateTime))
{
    // datetimeVM has default DateTime value
}
```

However, `Nullable<T>` is a wrapper class for structures that allows them have `null` value, therefore default value of `Nullable<T>` is `null`.

Comment: so in a linq statement I can do something like this `datetimeVM = dt == default(DateTime) ? dt : null;`

Comment: This is not a LINQ statement, this is [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) ( (condition) ? (TRUE expression) : (FALSE expression) ). But to answer your question, just do `datetimeVM = (dt == default(DateTime)) ? null : dt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 if  ((new DateTime()).Equals(dt)) {
...
}
```